# "Cannot Parse Condition" Error when utilizing the Items.Find method with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, search, outlook

I'm trying to search for emails I previously sent and reply to those emails.

I utilized the `Items.Find` method in the Outlook class to search for the subject line of those emails in my sent folder. The `Items.Find` method is not parsing the string.

I have an Excel sheet with Company Name, First Name, Last Name, Company email that I pull data from into defined variables and iterate through the list to search for the sent emails. I have another Excel sheet that contains the contents of the reply email I am writing.

```vb
'Define Variables
Sub SendReplyEmails()
Dim ol As Outlook.Application
Dim outm As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Object
Dim FilterText As String
Dim subjectLine As String
Dim searchString As String

Dim wsCont As Worksheet
Dim wsDash As Worksheet
Dim strHTML As String

Dim sig As String
Dim attachDoc As String

'Set Values
Set wsCont = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Contacts")
Set wsDash = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
vaData = wsCont.Range("Contact_Data").Value

groupNum = wsDash.Range("C5").Value
ccLine = wsDash.Range("C18").Value
attachNum = wsDash.Range("C22").Value
introLine1 = wsDash.Range("C29").Value
introLine2 = wsDash.Range("C30").Value
endingLine = wsDash.Range("C36").Value
signOff = wsDash.Range("C41").Value
nameLine = wsDash.Range("C42").Value
subjectLine = wsDash.Range("C14").Value

'For loop to run through each contact in list
For i = 1 To groupNum
    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set fol = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    searchString = subjectLine & vaData(i, 1)
    Debug.Print "searchString = " & searchString
    FilterText = "@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001f"" = searchString'"
    Set j = fol.Items.Find(FilterText)
    
    If j Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "J is nothing"
    End If
    
    If j.Class <> olMail Then
        Debug.Print "J is not an email"
    End If
        
    If Not j Is Nothing And j.Class = olMail Then
        Debug.Print "Executed"
        Set replyEmail = j.ReplyAll
        
        replyEmail.Display
        sig = replyEmail.HTMLBody
            
        replyEmail.To = vaData(i, 4)
        replyEmail.CC = ccLine
        
        replyEmail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        
        strHTML = "<html><body>" & "<section>" & "Hi " & vaData(i, 2) & ", " & "<br>" & "<br>" & introLine1 & _
        "<br>" & "<br>" & introLine2 & "<br>" & "<br>" & "<ul>" & "</ul>" & endingLine & "<br>" & "<br>" & signOff & "<br>" & nameLine & sig
        replyEmail.HTMLBody = strHTML
        
        replyEmail.Send
        
    End If
        
Next

End Sub
```

I messed around with the syntax of the `Items.Find` method according to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.find) but I have been unable to find one that works.

The search string is "Important: Event Title | Company Name, LLC".

Comment: `FilterText = "@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001f"" = searchString'"` you are passing in the literal string "searchString" instead of whatever is in that variable.  `searchstring` needs to be outside of quotes.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-string-comparison for examples

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I've realized in the code snip I shared, I accidently left in the extra " making searchString a literal string. However, even after removing it, I get the condition is not valid error - FilterText = "@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001f" = searchString.

Comment: We can't see what you're passing in with `searchString`, so it's difficult to make suggestions.  Do you maybe need to add single quotes around the search term?

Comment: The search string is "Important: Event Title | Company Name, LLC". Applying the single quotes avoids the parsing error but then I run into the same condition error.

Comment: What exactly is the "same condition error"?  Can you update your post to add your current code and the exact error(s) you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to replace a string literal with a variable in the search criteria string:

```
searchString = subjectLine & vaData(i, 1)
    Debug.Print "searchString = " & searchString
    FilterText = "@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001f"" = searchString'"
```

So, the filter string should look like that:

```
searchString = subjectLine & vaData(i, 1)
    Debug.Print "searchString = " & searchString
    FilterText = "@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001f"" = '" & searchString & "'"
```

Second, searching Outlook items with the exact subject line is not really a good idea. The `Subject` string may contain prefixes like RE or FW and other artifacts etc. So, you need to search for a phrase match instead:

```
searchString = subjectLine & vaData(i, 1)
    Debug.Print "searchString = " & searchString
    FilterText = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001E" _
    & Chr(34) & " ci_phrasematch '" & searchString & "'"
```

See [Filtering Items Using a String Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-string-comparison) for more information about that.

---

You may also find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: It makes sense to mark the answer then.